# How well, if at all, does Oracle NoSQL database integrate with Oracle RDBMS?

Tags: oracle, nosql

I currently have an application which runs on Oracle RDBMS and an area of new functionality which would be better supported by a NoSQL store.  I am wondering if Oracle NoSQL Database may be a good place to store this information and more concretely, can a single query span Oracle NoSQL and Oracle RDBMS.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/NOSQL/html/javadoc/oracle/kv/exttab/package-summary.html "This package contains the public API and Utilities for accessing Oracle NoSQL Database data through Oracle Database External Tables." - That's the only thing I can find as far as integration between the two, and doesn't look very "sexy" (EE only too). But I'm not familiar with the product.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle NoSQL Database integrates well with the Oracle database.  You can run an SQL query in Oracle Database that can reference data in the Oracle database as well as NoSQL Database.

Please see the Oracle NoSQL Database documentation for more details on external tables support.

You can also get an overview of the latest release here:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VT2n1QhIprQ

I'd suggest that you also post your questions relating to Oracle NoSQL Database to the OTN forum: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/forum.jspa?forumID=1388.  We monitor the forums regularly...

Happy Holidays.

Ashok Joshi
Senior Director, Oracle NoSQL Database development

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/NOSQL/html/GettingStartedGuide/introduction.html

"To make use of Oracle NoSQL Database, code must be written (using Java or C) that runs on the application server....The requests are made using the Oracle NoSQL Database Driver, which is linked into your application as a Java library"

So, I believe the answer is no with the exception of possibly the way Mat pointed out in the comments section